# Помогите объединить регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь сделать минипарсер формулы, на выходе должно быть 5 групп:

```
(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)
```

Есть 3 возможных варианта:

1. Если после буква заглавная, то после неё может следовать 'w', вторая группа в этом случае пустая:

   `([2-3]?)()([ACD]{1})([w]?)([2']?)`
2. Во втором случае вторая и четвёртая группы всегда пустые:

   `([2-3]?)()([acd]{1})()([2']?)`
3. Если вначале 2 цифры, то обязательно через '-' и обязательно первая меньше второй... т.е. **тут нужно как-то исключить вариант '3-3' из возможных**. Четвёртая группа в этом случае всегда пустая.

   `([2-3]{1})-([3-5]{1})([acd]{1})()([2']?)`

**Как объединить эти три правила в одну формулу?** Может быть, что-то можно записать компактнее?

Comment: В п. 3 числа произвольные?

Comment: @wcobalt первое число 2 или 3, второе любое от 3 до 5

Comment: но, если первое 3, то второе от 4 до 5

Comment: Меня могут закидать помидорами, но для объединения выражений используют `|`. Необходимо учитывать порядок вариантов, чтобы предыдущий вариант не перекрывал текущий, который больше подходит для ситуации.

Comment: @Adokenai да, но сбивается номерация групп в этом случае... или есть какая-то хитрость неизвестная мне... Получается вот такая колбаса: https://regex101.com/r/gRnbTK/1 Всё бы ничего, но при первом вхождении у нас группы 1-5, как и хотелось бы, при совпадении со вторым вариантом группы 6-10, с третьим 11-17 (там вообще аномалия какая-то, группа без захвата, но нумерация идёт)

Comment: @Isaev Третья группа вообще нужна? Да и само построение выражения вызывает вопросы. Не понятны пустые скобки. [вот как я переделал](https://regex101.com/r/NfoeUZ/1)

Comment: @Adokenai третья группа нужна, она понимает выражения начинающиеся с двух чисел через тире, твой вариант их теперь не видит, и апострофы вконце тоже не видит... пустые скобки добавлены, чтобы найденные логические единицы попадали всегда в свою группу, т.к. иначе в каждом варианте количество групп разное, чтобы потом не встраивать логику в программу по выбору информации с разных мест на основе количества групп на выходе

Comment: @Isaev Если не секрет, что за супер формулы такие?

Comment: @Adokenai из языка вращений шарнирных головоломок

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88671/discussion-between-adokenai-and-isaev).

Comment: В общем получилось следующее: https://regex101.com/r/gRnbTK/2
Работает корректно, если можно оптимизировать, буду раз предложениям

Comment: @Ver Nick приз в студию)

Comment: @Isaev А на каком языке вы используете эти регулярки ? В PCRE совместимых выражениях есть именованные группы. И если у языка использующего эту библиотеку есть интерфейс к ним, то можно в нескольких ветвях выбора использовать одно и то же имя. на выходе получите под именами захваты из сработавшего варианта.

Comment: @Mike но одинакого именовать группы вроде недопустимо, или? В данном случае Delphi, там вроде питоновский синтаксис регулярок, т.ч. должно быть, но я никогда не пробовал там с именованными группами работать, надо заценить

Comment: @Isaev В перле я пользовался одинаковыми именованными группами. Там проблем не было. но perl все таки законодатель моды в регулярках. Его новшества долго расходятся по другим программам

Comment: Последняя версия получилась такая: https://regex101.com/r/gRnbTK/3
Это работает правильно, как и было задумано, но очень медленно, можно видеть, что для этого примера потребовалось аж 2588 шагов... Хотелось бы это оптимизировать, т.к. критическое место. Знаю тут есть гуру в этой теме, помогали уже несколько раз в вопросах оптимизации регулярок. Могу оформить новым вопросом или в рамках конкурса оставить тут?

Comment: Сложно такое оптимизировать. Пока что предложу https://regex101.com/r/RMuVMt/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного оптимизированное для PCRE выражение на основе групп со сбросом нумерации захватывающих подмасок будет выглядеть как

```
(?<![^ ,\n])
(?|
  ([23]?)()([MSEURFBDL])(w?)|
  ([2-5]?)()([mseurfbdl])()|
  (?|(2)-([3-5])|(3)-([45]))([mseurfbdl])()
)
([2']?)
(?![^, \n])
```

См. [пример работы выражения онлайн](https://regex101.com/r/RMuVMt/2).

**Подробности**

- `(?<![^ ,\n])` - сразу перед текущей позицией не должно быть символа, отличного от пробела, запятой или сивола перевода строки
- `(?|` - группа со сбросом нумерации подмасок:

  - `([23]?)()([MSEURFBDL])(w?)|` - опциональная цифра `2` или `3` (№1), пустая строка (№2), буква `M`, `S`, `E`, `U`, `R`, `F`, `B`, `D` или `L` (№3) и опциональная буква `w` (№4)
  - `([2-5]?)()([mseurfbdl])()|` - опциональная цифра от `2` до `5` (№1), пустая строка (№2), буква `m`, `s`, `e`, `u`, `r`, `f`, `b`, `d` или `l` (№3) и пустая строка (№4)
  - `(?|(2)-([3-5])|(3)-([45]))([mseurfbdl])()` - цифра `2` (№1), дефис, цифра от `3` до `5` (№2) ИЛИ `3` (№1), дефис, цифра `4` или `5` (№2), буква `m`, `s`, `e`, `u`, `r`, `f`, `b`, `d` или `l` (№3) и пустая строка (№4)
- `)` - конец первой группы
- `([2']?)` - Группа №5: опциональный символ `2` или `'`
- `(?![^, \n])` -  сразу после текущей позиции не должно быть символа, отличного от пробела, запятой или сивола перевода строки.